# Changing position of Sprite in unity

Tags: java

I am trying to change the position of a sprite through a script. Here is the code for trying to change it. I tried it through the SpriteRenderer and the Sprite itself.

```
     void Update() { 
    checkMesh();

    spriteRenderer.enabled = true;
    spriteRenderer.transform.position.Set(10,10,1);
    sprite.rect.Set(10, 10, 100, 100);
    checkStart();

    checkForEnd();


}
```

Here is how I am grabbing the references to Sprite and the renderer

```
    spriteRenderer = this.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    sprite = spriteRenderer.sprite;
```

I can't seem to find why it won't work. Here is an image of the Hierarchy

[image]

I am trying to move the image named "bigpaddle" under "Expand Paddle"

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to move your sprite from a point a to point b in the game? **OR**, are you trying to make a sprite a child of some other game object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74891/unity-move-sprite-from-point-a-to-point-b

Reference this.  I'm assuming you know about dragging+dropping scripts directly onto game objects and that it isn't the problem.

Edit: Recommend you change the tags to your question if you want more people weighing in; Unity doesn't use Java, it uses C#, a variant of Javascript, and an implementation of Python.  `unity3d` is the most relevant tag for you.

Comment: Please apply [answer] to your post. This one is low quality, because once the external content is broken, this answer is totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

i am unfamiliar with position.set(), (dunno if it exits) but it think it expects a vector3.

normaly setting a position is done like this

```
transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are trying to set the parent or move the object, but:

- For SetParent you need the transform not the sprite, and the `transform.SetParent(transform)`
- For moving it, take the transform and say `transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0)`

Hope it helps!